# Div element is not showing/invisible on webpage

Tags: html, css

I was writing a basic HTML CSS code to try out something. After styling a div in css, the div disappeared from the webpage.

Please help.

Below is the code. The code is very basic.

Thank you !

```css
.bx1 {
  bottom: 50;
  left: 40;
  position: fixed;
}

.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="bx1">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but if you remove position fixed form .bx1 you shall see your Hello

Comment: I can see the div, are you taking about the hello text?

Comment: your position values need units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't leave bottom and left with blank units.

```
.bx1{
    bottom: 50px;
    left: 40px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style> 
.bx1{
bottom: 50px;
left: 40px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
background: red;
}

.box{
width: 80%;
height: 2000px;
background: green;
margin: 20px auto;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="bx1">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked ! Thank you so much ! I totally forgot about the units part !

Answer (score 1):

Remove position fixed, and as Prikesh stated, don't leave the bottom and left units blank.

```css
.bx1 {
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 40px;
 
}

.box {
  width: 80%;
  height: 2000px;
  background: green;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="bx1">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I need position fixed in my code. But adding units worked. Thank you !